# How can I make script files available to the client in a Node.js Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, express

I'm building a Node.js Express app. When my client Html file tries to get a `.js` file from the server (when running `<script src="somefolder/script.js"></script>`), it can't access it. What's the common way to make script files accessible to the client in an Express app?

Comment: You should put the public files in a static folder. `app.use(express.static('public'))`. Look for [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Express API](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use):

> Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory:
>   `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

For example above assume that you will have the following "./public" folder structure:

```
/public
    /javascripts
        /custom.js
    /stylesheets
        /style.css
...
```

In this case to get script, or whatever you want you will need to write the following url: `http://path_to_the_site/javascripts/custom.js`.

Note that you don't need to write "public" before "javascripts".